# how to apply moving average functions for multivariate time series models

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, moving-average

I have a multivariate time series models given below:

```
date         var1         var2         var3
01-01-2020   100          700          1300
01-02-2020   200          800          1400
01-03-2020   300          900          1500
01-04-2020   400          1000         1600
01-05-2020   500          1100         1700
01-06-2020   600          1200         1800
```

I am trying to apply moving average for each column and python has `rolling` function for it. Can you please help how to apply it for each column and update the columns such as `data[['var1']]=data[['var1']].rolling(window=100).mean()`

Answer (score 1):

You can select columns in list:

```
cols = ['var1','var2','var3']
df[cols] = df[cols].rolling(window=100).mean()
```

If need processing all columns:

```
df = df.rolling(window=100).mean()
```